# Automate user creation using google app script in Google Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I want to automate user creation in google as an Admin where I use app script to do it, however from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) I'm reading I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it right since I'm getting some errors in my code, like after **POST** and the Script not working.

```appscript
function createUsers() {
  const userjson = {
      "primaryEmail": "atest@example.com",
  "name": {
    "givenName": "afirstName",
    "familyName": "alastName"
  },
  "suspended": false,
  "password": "pass2022",
  "hashFunction": "SHA-1",
  "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true,
  "ipWhitelisted": false,
  "orgUnitPath": "myOrgPath",
  };

  const optionalArgs = {
   customer: 'my_customer',
   orderBy: 'email'
  };

  POST https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users

  try {
    const response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
    const users = response.users;

    //check if user exists
    if (!users || users.length === 0) 
    //create new user
    return AdminDirectory.newUser(userjson);

    // Print user exists
    Logger.log('User Existing');
    
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer)- Handle exception from the Directory API
    Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the line `POST https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users`.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: i tried removing https and it executes, however it does not create a new user

Comment: Have you enable the advanced service? Have you tried the code sample in the official docs -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#add_user), if you want to do it with Google Apps Script, you should format your code as follows:

```
function createUsers() {
  const userInfo = {
    "primaryEmail": "jvd@domain.com",
    "name": {
      "givenName": "Jackie",
      "familyName": "VanDamme"
    },
    "suspended": false,
    "password": "thisisasupersecret",
    "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true,
    "ipWhitelisted": false
  };
  try{
    AdminDirectory.Users.insert(userInfo);
    console.log("User added");
  } catch(error){
    const {code, message} = error.details;
    if(code === 409 && message === "Entity already exists."){
      console.log("User already exists");
    } else {
      console.log(`${code} - ${message}`);
    }
  }  
}
```

If you have any doubts about how to use the user resource payload, please refer to the [official documentation of the REST API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#User).